# Checksum java class file

Tags: java, class, jar, checksum

I am writing a piece of software that needs licensing from government authority, there are more modules of the same kind (but doing different work - math algorithms). I need to secure that anytime anyone (mostly a representative of government authority) comes to this software and asks for it (via network), the checksum for that particular module is printed out. I am writing this server in Java. I looked into `Serialization` but it only cares about the data (attributes) in the object and not the object behaviour or other logical structure - which this absolutely needs to care about. Hence I need to access the `.class` from within the running jar file and perform a checksum on it. The current structure is like this:

```
abstract class Module {
    public abstract void run();
    public String chsum ();
}

abstract class SimpleGame extends Module {
    /* not that important */
}

class GameX extends SimpleGame {
    public void run() {
        /* some magic */
    }
}
```

And when needed, upon receiving the proper message the network stack might call something like:

```
GameX gx = new GameX();
String checkSum = gx.chsum();
```

My current progress got me nowhere, I tried to access the .class file but without any luck - it works only if it is not a jar archive. And I need to supply the `Class` instance which is not a dealbreaker but it sure is not that handy. If I could get an array of bytes containing the compiled `.class` file that would be more than enough - to perform a checksum on that is a piece of cake using [MessageDigest](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/security/MessageDigest.html)

Comment: You can open the Jar file and read the entry. It wont be very secure, but thats the whole notiob of this checksum. A bit better would be to have your own classloader it can access the bytes at define time. I think it would be best to check a whole JAR even when it has only one class, then you can use the normal jar signer code.

Comment: I'm not very good at this sort of thing, but if you let your class be loaded by mechanism A and access the class file (in a jar or elsewhere) by mechanism B and calculate the digest from that: How is it guaranteed that the loaded class is from the file used by B? A safe way is to fetch a byte[] bytecode, calculate the checksum and then load from that (ClassLoader.defineClass).

Comment: What about going a step further and [sign your `.jar` file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9275780/is-it-possible-to-have-sha1-digest-in-java-manifest-file-without-actually-using)? You could also retrieve the hash values from the manifest file of the `.jar`.

Comment: Well I need to be able to change stuff (code) within the jar file without changing the checksum - because that's all that the government cares about.

Comment: It is a good point that I should load it myself and I can do the checksum there. I like this approach ... I'll have a look into that.